# How to get Python function that prints a word to print on same line with for loop?

Tags: python

I've got a function in Python

```
def wordPrint():
    print "word"
```

I want to use it to print 3 times on the same line using a for loop.

I would expect this code

```
for x in range(0,3):
    wordPrint(),
```

to output this

`word word word`

But I get them on new lines

Comment: You can't. `wordPrint` *always* adds a newline. Well, you could do something hacky, but it's probably best to change your approach altogether.

Comment: Use `os.stdout.write("word\r")` (or something like that). Other comments are correct, `print will always add a newline. Use `os.stdout.write()` which does not add the newline. The `\r` should return you back to the start of the current line.

Answer (score 0):

print() always prints on a new line. You'll have to use one print statement if you want one line of output. Using a for loop, you could do:

```
word = ""
for x in range(0,3):
    word += "word "
print(word)
```

Or, you could use the * operator (which is more pythonic).

```
print("word " * 3)
```